# Xamarin Forms - Show Cancel button in toolbar items instead of Back (iOS)

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to change the standard `Back` button in the `NavigationBar` on iOS to a `Cancel` button like the "New contact" screen in iOS.
I am using `Xamarin Forms`.

**EDIT:**

XAML of modal

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="Xrm.Mca.Views.MyModalView">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
            <ToolbarItem x:Name="Cancel" Text="Cancel" ></ToolbarItem>  
            <ToolbarItem x:Name="Save" Text="Save" ></ToolbarItem>  
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <TableView Intent="Form">
            <TableRoot>
                <TableSection Title="Details">
                    <EntryCell Label="Name" Placeholder="Entry your name" />
                    <EntryCell Label="Age" Placeholder="Entry your age" />
                </TableSection>
            </TableRoot>
        </TableView>

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Code-behind in the prior screen to open modal

```
async Task OpenModal()
{
    var page = new NavigationPage(new MyModalView ());
    await App.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync (page);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard convention of accomplishing your request is to [push a Modal](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AXamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushModalAsync(Xamarin.Forms.Page)) and use [ToolBarItems](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem). You can find an example of applying a ToolBarItem to your page on the [Xamarin Forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17339/navigationpage-and-toolbaritems).

Let me know if you need a more concrete example.

---

**UPDATED WITH EXAMPLE**

The two ToolbarItems would like like so:

```
var cancelItem = new ToolbarItem
{
    Text = "Cancel"
};

var doneItem = new ToolbarItem
{
    Text = "Done"
};
```

Now you can add these to your view:

```
this.ToolbarItems.Add(cancelItem);
this.ToolbarItems.Add(doneItem);
```

You can even bind the CommandProperty:

```
doneItem.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandProperty, "DoneClicked");
```

Or simply handle the event when the user taps the item:

```
doneItem.Clicked += (object sender, System.EventArgs e) => 
{
    // Perform action
};
```

Remember to [wrap your Modal in a NavigationPage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26651140/2399772), as the ToolbarItems otherwise will not appear.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I am already showing the modal and now I am struggling with adding **ToolbarItems** to the top of screen. I would like to add "Cancel" and "Done"

Comment: I've updated my answer with a code example. Please remember to up vote my answer and mark it as "Accepted" if it helped you out. Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick question, @gjfonte: are you in need of help in regards to Xaml or Code behind (C#)? It'd be nice if you had stated that more clearly in your question instead of simply tagging "xaml"

Also, just a quick note: if your Modal is not wrapped in a NavigationPage, your ToolbarItems will not shown:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26651140/2399772

Comment: Thanks David for your notes and suggestions. I have edit my question including the example of View.
How I can now move the `cancel` button to the left side?

Comment: @gjfonte Unfortunately, Xamarin doesn't support this at this very moment, but [many people are complaining over this on the forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21004/navigation-bar-left-toolbar-button), so hopefully we'll see a change in the coming versions of Forms. Currently, the only thing to do, is to make a custom renderer, as also suggested in the discussion above.

Good luck!

Comment: I will have a look but I am almost there, I just need to change some code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Demitrian How to set background color of toolbaritems from codebehind

Comment: @pArth savadiya Why not submit a new question on SO if you've got an issue you want to resolve? The comments aren't meant for asking questions

Answer (score 1):

Do the following in the constructor of the page doing the navigation push. This will work for all pages pushed on to the stack.

```
NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "Cancel");
```

Where this is the ContentPage (or any type of page) of course

Comment: I am including this code in the constructor and doesn't work.
My view constructor only contains the bindingContext, your code and InitializeComponent(). Do you have further idea? 
I have read something in Xamarin Form that it is not possible....