# How to add TitleIcon and button to navigation bar of NavigationPage?

Tags: xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, navigationbar

I am trying to add TitleIcon and reload button to Navigation Bar of NavigationPage but dont know how to do it. I tried to use Icon property for navigation page but it does not work. About adding buttons to navigationpage i have not found anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                x:Class="App.MasterDetailMenu"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App;assembly=App">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>

          <local:MasterPage/>

    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

   <MasterDetailPage.Detail >

    <NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor="#7FBE5D" x:Name="NavBar" Icon="image.png">


        <x:Arguments>
            <local:Feedbacks/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Comment: Have you tried pushing the page modally? In doing so [will allow you to add items, such as icons, to your toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733917/xamarin-forms-show-cancel-button-in-toolbar-items-instead-of-back-ios/30968945#30968945).

Comment: @Demitrian thanks! it worked just fine)))

Comment: Good to know :) Remember to upvote if you agree to the solution ;)

Comment: @Demitrian sure if you will add your answer as solution) not comment)

Comment: @Demitrian and also how to add title icon for toolbaritems?

Answer (score 2):

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class AboutPage : ContentPage
{
    public AboutPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationCommand = new Command(NavigationCommandToInfo);
        ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem() { Icon = "Info2.png", Command=NavigationCommand });
    }

    public ICommand NavigationCommand { get; }

    void NavigationCommandToInfo() =>
        Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
}
```