# How can i show an icon in xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, icons

I´m developing an app in xamarin forms and I want to know how show an icon in a menu, the image of this icon is in the resource folder (drawable). The menu is in a Inavigation page in the same project.

I´m trying this with the next code, but it doesn´t work:

```
*var iconlogin = new ToolbarItem
{
  Icon = "login.png"};*`

  *new Sample("Login", typeof(LoginPage), SampleData.DashboardImagesList[0], iconlogin.Icon, false, false)*
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I show an icon in xamarin?

Add the following code :

```
var settings = new ToolbarItem
{
    Icon = "icon.png",
    Text = "Settings",
};

this.ToolbarItems.Add(settings); //<-- this line
```

The `icon.png` in located in `Resource\Drawable` folder. If you want use the `ToolbarItem` in `xaml`, you need do :

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="Menu1" Activated="OnClick"  Order="Primary" Priority="0"  Icon="icon.png" />
    <ToolbarItem Name="Menu2" Activated="OnClick"  Order="Primary" Priority="1" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Effect :

[image]

For more information, you could refer to the [document](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-toolbar/) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733917/xamarin-forms-show-cancel-button-in-toolbar-items-instead-of-back-ios).