# Xamarin.forms toolbar Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to have the toolbaritems display right below the navigation bar? I also noticed that when I click a button within my toolbar to navigate to a new page the toolbar floats to the topleft corner of my phones screen and then disappears. I'm not sure why it does that and I would much rather have it simply disappear right away. I'm currently testing the toolbar on the android platform. Below is what it currently looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to have the toolbaritems display right below the navigation bar?

In `Xamarin.Forms` , you could use [ToolbarItem](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem/) to implement this feature.

If you want display `ToolbarItem` at the right corner, set the `order` of the `ToolBarItem` to `Secondary` to force the option into an overflow menu on Android :

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Share" Activated="EditClicked_Share" Order="Secondary" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Create" Activated="EditClicked_Create" Order="Secondary" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Effect :

[image]

If you want display `ToolbarItem` right below the navigation back button,

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Share" Activated="EditClicked_Share"  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Create" Activated="EditClicked_Create"  Order="Primary" Priority="1" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Save" Activated="EditClicked_Save"  Order="Primary" Priority="2" Icon="ic_action_content_save.png" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Effect :

[image]

Remember to [wrap your Modal in a NavigationPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646378/toolbar-item-not-showing-in-xamarin-forms/26651140#26651140), as the `ToolbarItems` otherwise will not appear. For more information, you could refer to the [article](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-toolbar/) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733917/xamarin-forms-show-cancel-button-in-toolbar-items-instead-of-back-ios).