# How to access tap or click of an toolbar image in android xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have placed an image inside toolbar like in the below code. I did this to have an toolbar icon on the left side.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/appicon"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I need to access the tap or click of the image in Activity.cs. 
It would be grateful, if you have any other way to place Toolbar icon on the leftside in xamarin forms.

Comment: @PaulKertscher am looking for a way to place toolbaritem on the left side of the toolbar in xamarin forms application

Comment: Alright, re-added the tag. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for a way to place toolbaritem on the left side of the toolbar in xamarin forms application

You could refer to my answer : [Xamarin.forms toolbar Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369488/xamarin-forms-toolbar-android/47387794#47387794)
.

Place `ToolbarItem` on the left side of the toolbar in `Xamarin.Forms`, put this code in `yourPage.xaml` :

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Share"  Activated="EditClicked_Share"   Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Create" Activated="EditClicked_Create"  Order="Primary" Priority="1" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Save"   Activated="EditClicked_Save"    Order="Primary" Priority="2" Icon="ic_action_content_save.png" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

> I need to access the tap or click of the image

In `yourPage.cs` :

```
private void EditClicked_Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Picture Clicked");
}
```

### Update :

This isn't currently supported in Forms,  you could write a [Custom Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) that overrides the base Android `Toolbar` renderer.

Herer is a simple solution, create a picture which color is same with the `Toolbar`, in my project, my picture is `blue.png` :

[image]

Place it left side of the `Toolbar`, add some blank `ToolbarItem` between the picture and your `ToolbarItem` to adjust the space.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem  Activated="EditClicked_Save" Order="Primary" Priority="0" Icon="ic_action_content_save"/>
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Priority="1" Icon="blue"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Effect :

[image]

Comment: My requirement is to have a toolbaritem on the left side of the toolbar.  The provided code by you will add toolbaritems on the right side.

Comment: @Santyy, I have update my answer, you could check it.

Comment: Yes, I solved my problem by placing a ImageButton in Toolbar.axml and handling click of that. Thanks

Comment: @Santyy, happy coding. : )