# TargetInvocationException in customized ContentPageRenderer Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, renderer

I'm trying to move a `Button` in the NavigationBar from the right side to the left in a custom page renderer in Android. `CropDetailPage` is a content page in the shared code.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CropDetailPage),typeof(CropDetailPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
public class CropDetailPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public CropDetailPageRenderer(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var bar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            bar.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Azure);
            // Only have 1 child
            bar.GetChildAt(0).SetX(10); 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this exception when I try to open the refered page

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

I've tried commenting the code inside my `OnElementChanged` method, but the exception keeps happening, so I know it's not coming from the logic.

Also, is this the right way to customize the appearance of a `Toolbar`? Since I wanted to move my button to the left, I just thought of changing the `X coordinate`.

Any ideas to what's happening ?

Edit: Xaml for button

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Back" Command="{Binding GoBackCommand}"></ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ContentPage.Content>
 ....
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: How did you place the `Button` in your `NavigationBar`, please post your code.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Posted

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to move a Button in the NavigationBar from the right side to the left

If your `Button` is in your `Toolbar.axml`, you could change the `Button`'s position like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
       <Button
           android:text="Button"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

## Update:

You could refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47389936/how-to-access-tap-or-click-of-an-toolbar-image-in-android-xamarin-forms/47404229#47404229):

Herer is a simple solution, create a picture which color is same with the `Toolbar`, in my project, my picture is `blue.png` :

[image]

Place it left side of the `Toolbar`, add some blank `ToolbarItem` between the picture and your `ToolbarItem` to adjust the space.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem  Text="Button" Order="Primary" Priority="0"/>
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Priority="1" Icon="blue"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmB65.png).

## Update 2:

You could try using [BoxView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/boxview/) from the blog: [Custom App Header in Forms](https://wolfprogrammer.com/2016/07/07/custom-app-header-in-forms/), it allows us to easily change height, icons, font-family background gradient for all content page with the header.

Comment: Thanks but I already seen that one. Doesn't really count as an answer. I wanted to learn about how could I do it with Renders